# gulp-cssimport doesn't adjust images' relative path

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using gulp-cssimport to import  different css files, but when I used a relative path to import images, the transformed images' path doesn't transform to the right path.

### file structures

[image]

### src/css/channel/index.css

```
@import url('../mod/common/common.css');
```

### src/css/mod/common/common.css

```
body {
    background-image: url('../../imgs/1.jpg');
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### dist/css/channel/index.css

```
body {
    background-image: url('../../imgs/1.jpg');
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dist/css/channel/index.css` is looking one directory too high.

Instead of:

```
background-image: url('../../imgs/1.jpg');
```

You're looking for:

```
background-image: url('../imgs/1.jpg');
```

This is because `imgs` is a *sibling* of `channel`.

Comment: dist directory is created by gulp, the gulp-cssimport plugin doesn't adjust the image path to the right one.